# Adding numpy array elements to new array only if conditions met

Tags: python, numpy

I need to copy elements from one numpy array to another, but only if a condition is met. Let's say I have two arrays:

```
x = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
y = ([])
```

I want to add numbers from x to y, but only if they match a condition, lets say check if they are divisible by two. I know I can do the following:

```
y = x%2 == 0
```

which makes y an array of values 'true' and 'false'. This is not what I am trying to accomplish however, I want the actual values (0,2,4,6,8) and only those that evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values you want like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

y = x[x%2==0]
# y is now: array([2, 4, 6, 8])
```

And, you can sum them like this:

```
np.sum(x[x%2==0])
# 20
```

**Explanation:** As you noticed, `x%2==0` gives you a boolean array `array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)`. You can use this as a "mask" on your original array, by indexing it with `x[x%2==0]`, returning the values of `x` where your "mask" is `True`. Take a look at the [`numpy` indexing documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more info.